# Swing UIManager.put doesn't seem to work right all the time. Bug or not?

Tags: java, swing, uimanager

I've been using UIManger.put to change the font of labels globally, but it seems like it works inconsistently. Sometimes does, sometimes doesn't.
UIManager does indeed save the new value on it's map.

For example, if you use:

```
final Font labelFont = new Font("Source Sans Pro", 0, 24);
UIManager.put("Label.font", labelFont);
```

And you use before/after creating the label:

```
System.out.println(UIManager.get("Label.font"));
```

it returns

```
java.awt.Font[family=Source Sans Pro,name=Source Sans Pro,style=plain,size=24]
```

But the label's font isn't changed always. Whats is wrong?

I've tried to change the property on the dispatch thread and out of it, but the result is the same.

Working right:
[image: working right]

Working wrong:
[image: working wrong]

The next both examples have the same problem.

Here is an example, try it many times and you will see, unless I'm the one I have something bugged on my computer (I tried it like 30 times, no exaggeration, without any problems, but it did happen after that):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public final class ElVecino {
  private JFrame frame;

  public ElVecino() {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.forLanguageTag("es-CL"));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ElVecino application = new ElVecino();
    application.setLookAndFeel();
    try {
      SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
        application.createAndShowGUI();
      });
    } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException exception) {
      Logger.getLogger(ElVecino.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
    }
  }

  public void createAndShowGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("testApp");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();

    System.out.println(UIManager.get("Label.font"));
    final JLabel label = new JLabel("Cargando...");
    contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println(UIManager.get("Label.font"));
  }
  /**
   * 
   */
  public void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
      for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
          javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException exception) {
      Logger.getLogger(ElVecino.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
    }
    final Font labelFont = new Font("Source Sans Pro", 0, 24);
    UIManager.put("Label.font", labelFont);
  }
}
```

Here is another example putting every GUI method on the dispatch thread, also gives me the same problem, just try it many times

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public final class ElVecino {
  private JFrame frame;

  public ElVecino() {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.forLanguageTag("es-CL"));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ElVecino application = new ElVecino();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      application.setLookAndFeel();
      application.createAndShowGUI();
    });
  }

  public void createAndShowGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("testApp");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();

    final JLabel label = new JLabel("Cargando...");
    contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  /**
   * 
   */
  public void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
      for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
          javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException exception) {
      Logger.getLogger(ElVecino.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
    }
    final Font labelFont = new Font("Source Sans Pro", 0, 24);
    final Font textFieldFont =  new Font("Source Code Pro", 0, 24);
    UIManager.put("Label.font", labelFont);
    UIManager.put("TextField.font", textFieldFont);
    UIManager.put("TextArea.font", textFieldFont);
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.font", labelFont);

  }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. Are you trying to set the `UIManager` before or after making your app visible?

Comment: I've done an example, it's not short but it works.

Comment: Your question is about the font of a label. Why would you write hundreds of lines of code to test this? Post a proper `MCVE` that demonstrates the problem. So all you need to do is 1) set the UIManager properties. 2) create a frame, 3) add a label to the frame. Also try it for different fonts if the above doesn't work. In other words, narrow down if the problem is with 1) your code 2) the UIManager.

Comment: What does "it works" mean? If the code works then why are you asking a question?

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, so explain me plz what is wrong with what I wrote. And I made it shorter, the other one was more like my application, but without other classes, now it's as you wanted to be (I hope, lol).

Comment: I know something is wrong because it's not the first time I've had this problem, but I think there must be some information about using UIManger.put that I don't know, and that is what I'm looking for,

Comment: @FlavioLópez Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Once you set swing properties, you need to call SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUi()

Answer (score 0):

> I think there must be some information about using UIManger.put that I don't know

Not about UIManager, but about Swing in general:

1. Swing components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. So I would set the UIManager defaults in the EDT as well.
2. The Swing tutorial recommends to use invokeLater(...), not InvokeAndWait(...). See the `LabelDemo` example code from [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for an example on how to structure your code.

Comment: I know that and I've tried it, but it doesn't fix the problem. I added another example so you can test it, if you want.

Comment: See my answer, need to call an additional method to actually apply the properties